# simple for loop produces odd results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to update the html of each button with its array index when I click on the h2.

i tried the using a for loop but it isn't updating every button only # 1, 3 but 2 and 4 remain the same. what am I doing wrong? thanks

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/96/

**HTML**

```
<div class='container text-center'>
    <h2>Click me to toggle the button</h2>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-large'>Test</button>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-large'>Test</button>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-large'>Test</button>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-info btn-large'>Test</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
var buttons = [
    $("button:eq(0)"), 
    $("button:eq(1)"), 
    $("button:eq(2)"), 
    $("button:eq(3)")
];

$("h2").click(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        buttons[i].text("Array element: " + i++);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: try to use http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

Answer (score 3):

Thats because you are incrementing in the middle of the loop

```
buttons[i].text("Array element: " + i++);
```

Change it to

```
buttons[i].text("Array element: " + i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have `i++` inside the loop.

```
buttons[i].text("Array element: " + i++);
```

make it

```
buttons[i].text("Array element: " + i);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var buttons = [
    $("button:eq(0)"), 
    $("button:eq(1)"), 
    $("button:eq(2)"), 
    $("button:eq(3)")
];

$("h2").click(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // here
        buttons[i].text("Array element: " + (i + 1)); // and here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0; i < 3;) {
    buttons[i].text("Array element: " + i++);
}
```

if you want to increment in the loop drop the third declaration in your for statement. Otherwise you'll be incrementing twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    buttons[i].text("Array element: " + i++);
}
```

change it to

```
 for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    buttons[i].text("Array element: " + i);
}
```

Note that, You made two mistakes, one is looping for only 3 elements and another is incrementing i twice.